# Jmeter - extracting data using Json Path Extractor

Tags: jmeter, jsonpath

I'm running a script in Jmeter and trying to extract data from the json returned, but I'm getting a WARN advice; however, using a Sampler I can see the content of the variable but when I'm using in a HTTP request Post or a IF controller, the variable is empty.

This is my json (including format):
{"positions":"2 8 9","length":13}

This is the JSON Patch extractor:
Destination Variable Name: passwordPositions
JSONPath expression: $.['positions']

This is the WARN I'm receiving:

2018/02/08 12:05:11 WARN  - com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor: Extract failed com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Expected to find an object with property ['positions'] in path $ but found 'java.lang.String'. This is not a json object according to the JsonProvider: 'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'.
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.PropertyPathToken.evaluate(PropertyPathToken.java:71)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.RootPathToken.evaluate(RootPathToken.java:62)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath.evaluate(CompiledPath.java:53)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath.evaluate(CompiledPath.java:61)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:187)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext.read(JsonContext.java:102)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext.read(JsonContext.java:85)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:502)
    at com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor.process(JSONPathExtractor.java:102)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:750)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:452)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Then with the sampler I see the content of the variable:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6jvO.png)

But when I use the variable as json in a POST request, the content of the json is:

POST data:
{
    "positions": "",
    "values": "1 1 5"
}

And this is the definition of my json test:
{
    "positions": "${passwordPositions}",
    "values": "1 1 5"
}

What am I doing wrong? I have checked several examples on Internet and I cannot find where the issue is?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried `$.positions`?

Comment: Yes, I did. The WARN is slightly different but the result is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JSON Path Examples](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#path-examples) you should be using `$.positions` instead.

Demo

[image: JMeter JSON Extractor]

Also be aware that starting from JMeter version 3.0 you have [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) built-in component so you won't have to use any plugins, see [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) article for more information if needed

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the issue. I have used the Regular Expression Extractor instead of Json extractor. I'm not sure about the reason, I saw using Postman, that maybe the response is not coming in 'real' json, it seems to be xml/html; so using the Regular Expression Extractor I can extract the data. 
My configuration of the extractor is:

Reference Name: passwordPositions

Regular Expression: "positions":"(.+?)"

Template: $1$

Match No.: -1